# listing sublevels of one column by the levels of other column

Tags: r, reshape2, dcast

It is possible that this question is already discussed somewhere on this site but I am not able to find it after several searches. 
Let us say my dataframe has only 2 columns which can be generated with below code

```
df=data.frame(brand=c('Audi','BMW','Audi','Toyota','Audi','Toyota'),
Model=c('A3','x', 'A4','Corolla','A5','Camry'))
```

Now I am interested in seeing for each brand, what are the models available. I do not want to sum or mean anything. This should be a simple solution but I am not able to find it.

Best I could find was using `dcast` from `reshape2` package. I do

```
dcast(df,brand+Model~.)
```

and I get this

```
   brand   Model       .
1   Audi      A3      A3
2   Audi      A4      A4
3   Audi      A5      A5
4    BMW       x       x
5 Toyota   Camry   Camry
6 Toyota Corolla Corolla
```

The first two columns are exactly what I want but I am thinking I am unnecessarily generating a third column and then discarding a later. Also, there is a chance this can be done without any additional library.

So my question is, is there a better or more efficient way of handling this?

(The actual data I have gives the count in the last column under '.' I do not know why the simplified example I created does not give the count but instead just repeats the value in second column. I will just take that up as a separate question if I have to!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply order the `data.frame` by `brand` and `Model`. If you have duplicated values, you can use `unique()` to only get distinct combinations.

```
unique(df[order(df$brand, df$Model), ])
```

returns

```
   brand   Model
1   Audi      A3
3   Audi      A4
5   Audi      A5
2    BMW       x
6 Toyota   Camry
4 Toyota Corolla
```